# $C-2I = (-1)^n \cdot 7^m$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cayley-hamilton

I am stuck on this linear algebra question. Please help!
Let C be a real $n \times n$ matrix such that $C^3 = I$

(i) What are the possible eigenvalues of C?

(ii) Show that 
$$\det(C-2I) = (-1)^n \cdot7^m$$
For some integer $m$ with $0 \leq m\leq n/2.$

I know how to do section i but added it in for the potential context.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is more readable. As it is now, it is quite hard to read when the text is compressed into a single block, especially without MathJax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$(i)$ If $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of $C$ and $C^3=I$ then $\lambda^3=1$

$(ii)$ $$C-2I=K\to C=K+2I$$
$$C^3=K^3+6K^2+12K+8I$$
$$K^3+6K^2+12K+7I=0$$

Now look the eigenvalues of $K$ and use that $\det K=\text{product of eigenvalues}$.

Comment: @LukeXu: you are welcome!